# Selenium PhantomJS custom headers in Java

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I want to add custom http request headers to Selenium PhantomJS. Specifically this header `Accept-Language: en-US`

I was able to figure this much out by reading other posts, but how would I fill out the second parameter of `setCapability` to set a custom header?

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();       
caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_CUSTOMHEADERS_PREFIX, "");
```

I've seen the other post on Stackoverflow but that one is related to Python and not Java.

Answer (score 3):

The PHANTOMJS_PAGE_CUSTOMHEADERS_PREFIX constant = 'phantomjs.page.customHeaders.'

So you need to add the header to the prefix.

In your case you want to do this:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
cap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_CUSTOMHEADERS_PREFIX + "Accept-Language", "en-US");
cap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "path to phantomjs executable");
```

Then simply pass the capabilities to the driver's constructor:

```
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(cap);
```